# android go back to previous view

Tags: android, back-button

I am working on a android application and i want to exit the application on back press when it comes to state where no view is available to go back. Until then it should go to the previous view on back press. How can i do this.

What i need

- Go back to previous view on back press.
- If you cant go back anymore show a toast and ask to exit the application.

my code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {



            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogInterface = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:


                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:


                    }

                    commonVariable.setSteps(0);

                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to exit the app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogInterface)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogInterface).show();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
@Override 
    public void onBackPressed() { 
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
        } else { 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogInterface = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:


                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:


                    }

                    commonVariable.setSteps(0);

                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to exit the app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogInterface)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogInterface).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if(fragment.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0){
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogInterface = new DialogInterface.OnClick....
        ....
    }
    else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                YourActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", null)
       .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Fragment Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) for this.

In the Fragmant Manager you have a method called:

```
getBackStackEntryCount()
```

If this returns 0 you can close your app or else you just go back.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
    boolean isHandled = false;
    if(fragment != null && (fragment instanceof BaseFragment)){
        isHandled = ((BaseFragment) fragment).onBackPressed();
    }
    if(!isHandled){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if(fragmentManager != null){
        fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

In BaseFragment:

```
public boolean onBackPressed()
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    if(manager != null){
        int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count > 0) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        } else {
            if(isAdded()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Are you sure?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showDialog();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
...
onPositiveButtonClick(){
   getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: i have used "addToBackStack("back")" in every fragmentManager i've used. So i can go back to previous views now. But the problem is when there is no more back to go,the app just quits without a message. How can i give a toast when no more back is available

Comment: But what wrong with this         
int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count > 0) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        } else {
            if(isAdded()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Are you sure?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                showDialog();
            }
        }

show dialog and when OK pressed just finish Activity and that's it